# Why doesn't my php function return a json formatted value?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to store a couple of form fields in a mysql database. These specific fields can have multi selected values. So i like to store the value as json_encode formatted value.

Now when I code per form field i can store the values in json format in the mysql db. Because of the repetitions i tried this function but this returns an array

```
function radioValue($radiodata) {
    $tmpArray = array();
    $tmpArrayLen = count($radiodata);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $tmpArrayLen; $i++) {
        $tmpArray[$i] = $radiodata[$i];
    }
    $tmpValue = json_encode($tmpArray);
    return $tmpValue;
}
```

So not {"1":"value1"} but ["value1"]

What have I overlooked??

btw this is the part why worked for each field

```
$tmpArray = array();
        $len = count($posted_data["field1"]);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $tmpArray[$i] = $posted_data["field1"][$i];
        }
        $storeValue = json_encode($tmpArray);
```

Comment: An aside,you put $radiodata in another array and then enocde it - just directly encode $radiodata

Comment: `["value1"]` is [valid JSON](https://3v4l.org/XEbg1) and it is the JSON representation of the data you put in `$tmpValue`. Why do you expect it to be `{"1":"value1"}`? You put values in `$tmpValue` starting with index `0`, the output of `json_encode()` is correct.

Comment: This is the difference between a numeric array and an associative.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Can you give us a look at how $radiodata looks

Comment: @eeetee $radiodata is an array of multiple selected formfield values

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode it after you encode:

```
$futureArray = radioValue($radiodata);

$array = json_decode($futureArray);
```

Also, add a `true` as the second parameter and it will be a associative array

```
$array = json_decode($futureArray, true);
```

Comment: He wants json returned,so I dont know what question you are answering.

Comment: `json_decode('["value1"]')` returns array anyway because the value encoded in the JSON is an array, not an object. Remark the square brackets.